# getDefaultDisplay().getRotation(); returns always same value

Tags: android, camera, rotation, orientation

I´m trying to get the device orientation when taking a photo from a custom camera Activity.
Previously, I checked everywhere how to achieve it, and got no results to the solutions people suggest.

I´m using this line of code to retrieve the orientation with no results. It always returns 1. I´m using a Samsung Galaxy S III for developing, if it helps.

```
 int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Log.d(TAG, "Taken rotation " + rotation);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int orientation;
    // if the device's natural orientation is portrait:
    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && height > width ||
        (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && width > height) {
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation = 270;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "portrait.");
                orientation = 0;
                break;              
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you restricted your Activity to landscape orientation? Maybe you set your phone to lock screen orientation?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked it in advance, because I set it to landscape for the camera layout. I quitted it and instead of returning me 1 was 0 all the time. That´s why I asked it throw here

Comment: Probably I don't understand you correctly. When you lock the activity to Landscape, you will only receive Landscape rotation from the WindowManager. If you lock to Portrait, you will only receive Portrait rotation. You can check the accelerometer about the Euler angels even if the orientation is locked.

Comment: No, you were right. The matter is that even not locking either to landscape or portrait returns me different values. I will try to check the orientation with the accelerometer. But I wanted to avoid this last solution. Thanks!

Comment: Finally I fixed it, with the sensor and works perfectly.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score -2):

This is a guess based on what I know but I'm thinking Surface.ROTATION_90 is a constant integer name.  Think of it like having this:

```
final int Surface.ROTATION_0 = 0;
final int Surface.ROTATION_90 = 1;
final int Surface.ROTATION_180 = 2;
final int Surface.ROTATION_270 = 3;
```

at the beginning of your program.  When a precompiler sees one of these constants it automatically replaces it with the integer equivalent.  When you initialize you're int rotation and set it to one of these the int holds the value that constant has been initialized at.
So, if you want to check Surface.Rotation directly you'll probably have to call getRotation() every time you check;

Something like:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
    {
        //whatever you need to do here
    }
```

etc.

or you can simply check for the integers these constants evaluate as.

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation;
if(rotation == 0)
    {
        //whatever you need to do here
    }
```

etc.

Personally I'd go with the second option.  Not having to call getRotation for every check might mean a small improvement in the runtime but its a good habit to minimize processor use whenever possible.